# Verifying ("...", { case (a,b) => ..} ) can't be compiled

Tags: forms, validation, playframework-2.0

From the play2's doc: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaForms, there is a sample code:

```
val loginForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "email" -> nonEmptyText,
    "password" -> text
  ) verifying("Invalid user name or password", { 
      case (e, p) => User.authenticate(e,p).isDefined 
  })
)
```

But it can't be compiled, the error message is:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- missing parameter type for expanded function The argument types of an anonymous 
 function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5) Expected type was: ?
```

It should be wrote as:

```
verifying("Invalid user name or password", params => params match { 
    case (e, p) => User.authenticate(e,p).isDefined 
}
```

My play version is latest play2.1-SNAPSHOT(2012-03-18).

Is there something wrong with the doc, or do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are outdated/wrong, your second version is correct. You can fix the docs yourself, it's a wiki.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems I don't have the permission to modify it.